# Is there any way to upload any video file to Dropbox using Angular?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angular, mean-stack, mean

I want to upload a video mp4 file to the Dropbox with the help of Angular or MEAN stack. My ultimate goal is to upload the video to the particular location and then I want to save the video link somewhere so that I can get the video link and user can play the Dropbox video directly in my web page and the user doesn't need to go to Dropbox to watch the video.

I tried using Dropbox saver API https://www.dropbox.com/developers/saver but I'm not able to get the video link to play it.

Comment: Have you tried to search? for example: https://github.com/christiansmith/ngDropbox

Comment: Yes, I tried ngDropbox but It does not have the functionality to get the link and sign out. It is still in development mode.